# Restricted bash circumvention via SSH command execution

Tags: ssh, bash, openssh

EDIT: After much digging, this is almost certainly a result of `/etc/profile.d/...` being called before rbash is executed, and therefore not a problem with restricted bash in itself.

There seems to be a trivial rbash circumvention, whereby an SSH user can simply request that bash be executed.

The environment consists of a restricted `$PATH`, with a tiny subset of commands available.  The `id` command is not available, which is what I base the following transcript on:

```
testuser@jumphost:~$ id
-rbash: id: command not found
```

.. but then ..

```
testuser@jumphost:~$ ssh localhost "bash"
testuser@localhost's password:  
id
uid=3033(testuser) gid=4033(jumpuser) groups=5033(foogroup) context=jumpuser_u:jumpuser_r:jumpuser_t:s0
```

..bash gets called; restricted shell has been circumvented.

I've tried to implement rbash being called via a `Match Group` / `ForceCommand` in the `sshd_config`, and while this *does* call rbash for me, the problem of being able to simply execute bash still exists.

We are not using public keys by default for the external users due to logistical reasons, so the ability to `"command="` in the `~/.authorized_keys` file is not an option.  We'd also like to offer more than just ssh to the users.. a `kinit` / `klist` as well a few other menial programs.

Is there a mechanism to restrict this behaviour?

Comment: depends on what you want to allow to execute.

Comment: @Jakuje - Let's say that only the ssh command should be available on the system, to jump further into the network.

Comment: For that you don't even need a shell access. There is the `-W` switch doing that using only IO forwarding.

Comment: @Jakuje - thank you for the reply.  It turns out that our local requirements dictate that a user should be able to jump onto the box itself. My concern is the circumvention around rbash though.

Comment: This looks more like a configuration issue. A properly setup restricted shell should not be able to execute the normal bash and properly setup SSH restrictions should not allow execution of arbitrary commands. Migrating the question will probably not help much because it is missing the information which are needed to help, i.e. the specific parts of the configuration.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks - i've edited the question to clarify a few things.

Comment: But if you performed `Match Address 127.0.0.0/16` and then `ForceCommand /bin/false`, wouldn't it disable the circumvention you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

In closing, the solution was to better control the initial environment between the time of successful authentication, and the calling of rbash.

This was achieved with a wrapper shell which calls a "clean" bash with the flags `--restricted`, `--rcfile ...`, `--noprofile`, etc.... and a default case which logs the attempt at execution before exiting.

With apologies for the alarmist title...